# Installshield Express write to registry during install

Tags: c#, installshield, installshield-le

is it possible to access entered information during install later in my application?
Can i write this to registry and how ?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Express edition doesn't make it obvious how to do this, but it's actually really easy. Those fields are wired up to Windows Installer Properties. I believe they are `USERNAME` and `COMPANYNAME` repsectively, but you can verify by taking a verbose log file and looking for the properties that have the values you enter. Once you know the name, all you have to do is reference the properties in your registry, and their values will be written by Windows Installer. Here are example steps in the registry view:

1. Create your target registry key
2. Add a string value with your chosen data name
3. For the data value, provide `[USERNAME]` or `[COMPANYNAME]`